# Solution of differential equation $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having a lot of trouble with this exercise. I found what $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ really are but I can't answer the last question where it says to divide the left by $y^7$ .

[image: problem]

Thank you.

Comment: What software is this? These sort of questions make me cringe - this is not the way students should be learning ordinary differential equations.

Comment: It's called webwork by MAA @Axion004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M(x,y)=y-4y^7$ and $N(x,y)=-y^5-6x$.  Upon dividing by $y^7$, we get $(y^{-6}-4)\operatorname dx+(-y^{-2}-6xy^{-7})\operatorname dy=0$.

The LHS is exact.  So integrating,  we get $(y^{-6}-4)x+y^{-1}=C$.

Comment: Thank you that's what I was missing! @ChrisCuster